# scipy.stats converter normal z scores to p value Python3

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, scipy, normal-distribution, valueerror

struggling a bit with this little converter, I couldn't get it to take me past the first input, which is repeatedly asked for. Is there a more elegant way to get around the ValueError problem that gets me out of the loop?

EDIT: I also played around with the position of the a=1 and a=0's and when I do that, it stops asking me for input but it just runs the script without asking me for the second user input.

Thanks folks!

```
import scipy.stats as st
a=1
while a==1:
    try:
        choice = input('Press 1 for percentages to Z-Score, 2 for Z-score into percentages, one tailed')
        if choice ==1:
            percentage = input('Enter value')
            print(st.norm.ppf(percentage))
            a=0
        if choice ==2:
            score = input('Enter value')
            print(st.norm.cdf(score))
            a=0
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Entry')
        a=1
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about how the code is wrong, I forgot to check for the basics:

**Convert your inputs before processing!!!**

I just converted both inputs into floats and now it works like a charm, including asking for new input in case it's an invalid entry.

```
import scipy.stats as st
a=1
while a==1:
    try:
        float(choice = input('Press 1 for percentages to Z-Score, 2 for Z-score into percentages, one tailed'))
        if choice ==1:
            percentage = float(input('Enter value'))
            print(st.norm.ppf(percentage))
            a=0
        if choice ==2:
            score = float(input('Enter value'))
            print(st.norm.cdf(score))
            a=0
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid Entry')
        a=1
```